# Absolute path in python function in a docker image

Tags: python, docker

I have the following function to remove scraped images from the project directory:

```
import os

# Function to delete all .jpg files from project directory
def remove_jpg():

    # script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    # rel_path = "/Users/myname/Documents/project_directory/"
    # abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)

    path = "/Users/myname/Documents/project_directory/"
    for file in os.scandir(path):
        if file.name.endswith(".jpg"):
            os.unlink(file.path)

# Main function ----
if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_jpg()
```

When I create my Docker image through `docker build -t project-test1 .`, and run the project in the Docker Desktop app, I always get the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myname/Documents/project_directory/'`

I have tried making the `path` variable something not absolute - but I've had no luck in getting it to run by utilizing the commented out code in the above function. Is this an issue with the `COPY . .` in the Dockerfile itself, or bad code in the function?

Comment: A Docker container runs in an isolated filesystem; if you run this script inside a container, it can't see the host `/Users` path and can't delete files there.  It might be easier to run this script outside of Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `COPY . .` copies the content of the current folder in the root directory of the container image (unless you previously changed the working folder with `WORKDIR`).

The path in the script points to your local directory, which won't generally be a valid path inside your container. To make your code work locally and inside the container, you should avoid hard-coding filenames by leveraging relative paths or specifying the target directory through script arguments or environment variables.

By the way, you can check the actual paths of the files inside the container running `docker run -it project-test1 bash` and look around.